# how to handle conflict between predefined Entities and custom entity in luis.ai

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying a simple example for leave application. I'm using `datetimev2` entity to find the duration in the utterance. But,

`**Apply annual leave**` `how may ....` for this kind of utterance Luis applying datetimev2 entity.

In the first example, `annual` is leave type, but am getting it in datetimev2 and also in `leave_type` entity.
The second example, `may` considering as `datetimev2` entity.

**Updated**
Two entities am getting from the sentence "applya annual leave", `Entities[1]` having `leavetype`entity, but in code `result.TryFindEntity("leavetype",out leavetype)` is `null` only when leavetype is **annual** and also getting `builtin.datetimev2.daterange` but not getting from the result to variable.

Other than **annual** it's working properly,able to get result value correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Praveen,

With regards to the datatimev2 issue, if LUIS can detect that a word or phrase can be categorized as multiple different entities then it will return all possible entities in the result. As such, you will need to build logic into your bot/app that consumes the LUIS results that can handle multiple entities in the JSON result.

However, if the issue is regarding being able to add custom entities, the option is to turn off the pre-built entities, label your custom entities in the utterances, then turn the pre-built entities back on.

Comment: update my question, added code for reference tried to handle the result but not working for only `annual`.